# Help integrating potential of interaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, integration

I'm having trouble integrating a potential that is very present in many theories regarding Condensed Matter Physics. The potential I'm trying to integrate is $$\int_{0}^{\alpha}d^3\textbf{r}\frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|^{2}},$$ where $r$ and $r'$ are three-dimensional vectors and therefore the integral must be performed over $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, in particular, over $r_{x}^{2}+r_{y}^{2}+r_{z}^{2}\leq \alpha^{2}$.

Even Mathematica seems to have a hard time integrating and evaluating it. It won't go further than the first integration variable. Many theories I'm handling require integrating this function and I'm completely stuck. Apparently the solution depends on the function $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-x^{2}}{4x}\ln{|\frac{1+x}{1-x}|}.$$

Comment: Is this supposed to be a volume integral or 3 integrals over $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: @bnosnehpets In the integral, $d\textbf{r}=dxdydz$, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the $z$-axis be parallel with $\textbf{r}'$ and use standard spherical coordinates, then $|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|^2=r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta$. We have
$$\begin{align}
&\int^\alpha_0\int^\pi_0\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta}r^2\sin\theta\,d\phi d\theta dr\\
&\quad=2\pi\int^\alpha_0\frac{r}{2r'}\int^\pi_0\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left[\ln{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\theta)}\right]\, d\theta dr\\
&\quad=\pi\int^\alpha_0\frac{r}{r'}\left[\ln{(r^2+r'^2+2rr')}-\ln{(r^2+r'^2-2rr')}\right]  dr\\
&\quad=\frac{2\pi}{r'}\int^\alpha_0rln\left[\frac{|r+r'|}{|r-r'|}\right]dr\\
&\quad=\frac{\pi}{r'}\left[r^2ln\left[\frac{|r+r'|}{|r-r'|}\right]\right]_0^\alpha-\frac{\pi}{r'}\int_{0}^{\alpha}r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\ln|{r+r'}|-\ln|{r-r'}|\right)\,d r\\
&\quad=\frac{\pi\alpha^2}{r'}ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]-\frac{\pi}{r'}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\frac{r^2}{r+r'}-\frac{r^2}{r-r'}\,d r
\end{align}$$
Change variable $u=r+r'$ for the first integral and $v=r-r'$ for the second
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\pi\alpha^2}{r'}ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]-\frac{\pi}{r'}\left(\int_{r'}^{\alpha+r'}u-2r'+\frac{r'^2}{u}\,d u-\int_{-r'}^{\alpha-r'}v+2r'+\frac{r'^2}{v}\,d r\right)\\
&\quad=\frac{\pi\alpha^2}{r'}ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]-\frac{\pi}{r'}\left(\left[\frac{u^2}{2}-2r'u+r'^2\ln(u)\right]_{r'}^{\alpha+r'}-\left[\frac{v^2}{2}-2r'v+r'^2\ln(v)\right]_{-r'}^{\alpha-r'}\right)\\
&\quad=\frac{\pi\alpha^2}{r'}ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]-\frac{\pi}{r'}\left(\frac{\alpha^2+2r'\alpha-\alpha^2+2r'\alpha}{2}-4r'\alpha+r'^2ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]\right)\\
&\quad=\pi\alpha\left(2+\frac{\alpha^2-r'^2}{\alpha r'}ln\left[\frac{|\alpha+r'|}{|\alpha-r'|}\right]\right)=4\pi\alpha\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-\left(\frac{r'}{\alpha}\right)^2}{4\left(\frac{r'}{\alpha}\right)}ln\left[\frac{|1+\left(\frac{r'}{\alpha}\right)|}{|1-\left(\frac{r'}{\alpha}\right)|}\right]\right)
\end{align}$$